# Attempted import error: 'react-table' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactTable')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

React Table Import error

Code import style below :

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
```

While its running, its showing error message like this

> Attempted import error: 'react-table' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactTable').

What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of react-table supports/uses hooks. to import react-table like `import ReactTable from 'react-table'` use [react-table-6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6) which is `react-table` version `6.11.0`

Install

```
# Yarn 
$ yarn add react-table-v6

# NPM 
$ npm install react-table-v6
```

Import

```
// ES6
import ReactTable from 'react-table-v6'
// ES5
var ReactTable = require('react-table-v6').default
```

or use the latest version which is `7.0.0-rc.15`

```
import {
 useTable,
 useGroupBy,
 useFilters,
 useSortBy,
 useExpanded,
 usePagination,

} from 'react-table'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error talks about there is no named default export like `ReactTable`. You might need to import objects differently.

Maybe you can try as the following:

```
import * as ReactTable from 'react-table'
```

Additionally I checked **react-table** on the [official npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) and I see there are examples like the following:

```
import { useTable, useFilters, useGlobalFilter } from 'react-table';
```

I guess you might want to use just few specific things from the library thus I suggest to go with importing only the required features like `import { } from 'react-table'` where between `{ }` you list what you need.

Comment: how to link up css ? @norbitrial